# Highchart chart based on timestamp under x-axis and close undr y-axis

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts, linegraph

I have created a chart with bar and line graph using highchart plugins. The chart is coming but the problem is that actually I need the y axis to be close and x-axis to be timestamp. But in my chart it is plotting based on volume and timestamp, also I am not able to get the ohlc values under tooltips on mouse-over, I am getting undefined for all those values.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

M,y code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcvc79uc/1/)**

```
var ohlc = [],
      volume = [],
      dataLength = data.length,
      i = 0;

    for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
      ohlc.push([
        new Date(data[i].TIMESTAMP).getTime(), // the date
        parseFloat(data[i].OPEN), // open
        parseFloat(data[i].HIGH), // high
        parseFloat(data[i].LOW), // low
        parseFloat(data[i].CLOSE) // close
      ]);

      volume.push([
        new Date(data[i].TIMESTAMP).getTime(), // the date
        parseFloat(data[i].VOLUME) // the volume
      ]);
    }

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 0
      },

      title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
      },

      yAxis: {
        labels: {
          align: 'right',
          x: -3
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Volume'
        },
        height: '100%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
      },


      plotOptions: {
        area: {
          fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {
              x1: 2,
              y1: 0,
              x2: 0,
              y2: 2
            },
            stops: [
              [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
              [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
          },
          marker: {
            radius: 2
          },
          lineWidth: 1,
          states: {
            hover: {
              lineWidth: 1
            }
          },
          threshold: null
        }
      },

      series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: ohlc,
        height: '35%',
        yAxis: 0,
        color: '#D8D8D8'

      }, {
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volume,
        height: '35%',
        yAxis: 0
      }],

       tooltip: {
                   formatter: function() {
                         return 'O : '+this.open+' <br/>'+ 
                                'H : '+this.high+' <br/>'+
                                'L : '+this.low+' <br/>'+
                                'C : '+this.close+' <br/>'+
                                'V : '+this.volume+' <br/>'+
                                'R : '+this.rate;
                        },
       backgroundColor: null,
       useHTML: true,
       positioner: function() {
          return {
            x: 0,
            y: 90
          };
        }
       }
    });
```

Comment: I'm confused - why are you sending OHLC data to a column series? The column series expects a single y value, not multiple. If you want to plot the full OHLC set, you should use Highstock, and the OHCL series type. If you want to plot a column of the closing value, you need to build an array of the closing values instead.

Comment: @jlbriggs I am using Highstock.js, can you please show me an example to plot a column of the closing value and x-axis to be timestamp

Comment: Wy you push multiple values, maybe better is push only close value: http://jsfiddle.net/zjsuhkb4/ ?

Comment: @AlexMan - you just need to build an array for the closing value, exactly like you're building the array for volume, and use that as your data.